# table join order is changed between w/ and w/o keys

Tags: sqlite

I found the query plan is changed between w/o and w/ keys.

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
    `name`  TEXT,
    `value` NUMERIC,
    PRIMARY KEY(`name`)
) WITHOUT ROWID;

CREATE TABLE `ranges` (
    `begin` TEXT,
    `end`   TEXT,
);

explain query plan select distinct t1.name as name from data t1, ranges t2 where t1.name between t2.begin and t2.end order by name;

"0" "0" "1" "SCAN TABLE ranges AS t2"
"0" "1" "0" "SEARCH TABLE data AS t1 USING PRIMARY KEY (name>? AND name<?)"
"0" "0" "0" "USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT"
```

If I defined begin and end as keys,

```
CREATE TABLE `ranges` (
    `begin` TEXT,
    `end`   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`begin`,`end`)
);
```

the query plan is changed to the following.

```
"0" "0" "0" "SCAN TABLE data AS t1"
"0" "1" "1" "SEARCH TABLE ranges AS t2 USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_ranges_1 (begin<?)"
```

The first query plan is better because in my case data table is much larger than ranges.

I read https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html. It says join order is defined by sqlite's default choice w/o analysis results. Does adding those keys change the default choice? Is there any other trick to let SQLite use the first query plan w/o providing stat data?

Also, is the default choice non-changed? Will it be changed later? I use 3.22.

I also notice that if I do not use order by and distinct, it always uses the first plan

```
explain query plan select t1.name as name from data t1, ranges t2 where t1.name between t2.begin and t2.end;

"0" "0" "1" "SCAN TABLE ranges AS t2"
"0" "1" "0" "SEARCH TABLE data AS t1 USING PRIMARY KEY (name>? AND name<?)"
```

Comment: Without ANALYZE on an indexed column, the query optimizer does not know the size of the tables. Anyway, the page you linked to tells you how to order tables in a join.

Comment: @CL the link says sqlite preserves CROSS JOIN order. In my case changing the statement to "from range t2, data t1" does not help. I guess CROSS JOIN cannot have where clauses?

Comment: `,` is not the same as `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you. "from range t2 cross join data t1" makes it work: scanning t2+indexing t1. But when "order by name" is also used, a "temp b tree" is used. The scanning t1+indexing t2 plan does not need the tmp b tree for "order by".